# Compose merged cells on lazy column

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-multiplatform

I'm trying to write a list of building and rooms with compose.

My goal is to achive something like this.

[image]

I'm very used to recyclerviews in android, and know how to achieve this by it, but not that familiar with compose.

As far as I know, nested lazy columns are not allowed, so I tried using a single lazy column which consists of a single lazy column that represents a 'floor', and the room list to be displayed inside on a foreach loop. It looks like this;

```
LazyColumn{
  items(floor) {
     Row{
        Text(text = floor.floorName) 
        floor.roomList.foreach { room ->
            Text(room.roomName)
        }
     }
  }
}
```

This works, but when there are 1000+ items in my lazy column, it takes 7~8 seconds for this UI to be displayed.

Is there a way to optimize this? Something like recyclerview's RecyclerViewPool?

Comment: Does it take so long to display even a completely static local list? It would be helpful to see the real implementation.